# How do I update my Entities using Scaffoling process in EFCore 3.1 -- Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: entity, ef-core-3.1, scaffold

I'm able to run my API and make calls which get data from the DB. Then when I try to update my Entities - after making db changes I get the error:

`Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

The stack trace is:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext 'Server=connection-string;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir Context -OutputDir Entities -Context HomeaZZonEntities -Force

Build started...
Build succeeded.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TrySetMetaData(_SqlMetaDataSet metaData, Boolean moreInfo)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.GetColumns(DbConnection connection, IReadOnlyList`1 tables, String tableFilter, String viewFilter, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 typeAliases)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.GetTables(DbConnection connection, Func`3 tableFilter, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 typeAliases)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:e9dbb919-9783-48c3-ae86-a6fda3d98427
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I tried everything from all the other posts like modifying the timeout time - but it still fails after about 15 seconds.

However I did work a few months ago when I did my last update.

Answer (score 1):

run Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

You can also reference this
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: correct, I had to use my local db... but this must be a bug with Microsoft Azure as I was able to Scaffold from an Azure db just a few weeks ago...